# Repair EFI/GPT Bootloader for virtual Windows 10

Tags: windows, bootloader, gpt, efi, repair

An interrupted system update caused the Windows 10 Pro on my virtual machine to get into a Diagnostic and Repair Mode loop and I am trying to fix. I need to access and use a certain program that is only installed on this machine and that I lost the setup files for. Using the command window I can browse through all the files, so the hard drive is okay, only Windows won't boot.

As far as I understand Windows 10 automatically means that my computer is using UEFI/GPT and not MBR/BIOS.

I tried several solutions that can be found online, among them formatting the EFI volume and rewriting the boot files using `bcdboot`. Unfortunately this failed an now I Windows is not even recognized as an installed operating system upon startup.

I use the Windows 10 image file hooked to the virtual machine as an emulated CD. From there I can boot into the restore settings and start the command window.

There are several procedures that are recommended in the tutorials I found, some of which are not working properly for me. I need help to interpret the state of the computer to figure out what are the necessary steps to recover my Windows installation.

For example I was supposed to run

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

to rewrite the bootloader data. However, I get the error message `access denied`. When looking for a fix for that I found I should first execute

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s V: /f ALL
```

which was supposed to copy the boot information files from the Windows installation to the bootloader partition. However, I got the message `BFSVC Error: Could not open the BCD template store. Status = [c000000f]`. When looking for how to fix this I found that I rebuilding the BCD should help and the steps where

```
attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
del c:\boot\bcd
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Resulting error message: The directory `C:\boot` did not exist. I was looking for fixes but I ended up using a USB flash drive to simply copy the entire folder `C:\boot` from another Win 10 Pro computer. After that I could execute the commands above.
Problem now, after the rebuild command:

```
Number of identified Windows installations: 0
```

The fix to that was supposed to be to recreate the BCD, so I started going in circles. I tried more desperate moves to recreate the bootloader:

```
X:\sources> diskpart
DISKPART> list disk
DISKPART> sel disk 0
DISKPART> list vol
DISKPART> sel vol 5
DISKPART> assign letter=V:
DISKPART> exit
X:\sources> format V: /FS:FAT32
bootrec /fixboot
```

Which resulted in the same `access denied` error but now my computer would only start with the installation media on the emulated CD. `bcdboot C:\Windows /s V: /f ALL` would now only say `File transfer failed` or so.
I found that using

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS
bootrec /fixboot
```

would actually run successfully, but not help my booting problem at all.
So I tried to get more creative and fix the missing BCD template store issue by putting the entire `C:\Windows\System32\config` folder of my other Windows installation onto my USB drive and using:

```
bcdboot F:\Windows /s V: /f ALL
```

Which felt like progress, because it actually did something, but resulted in an error message of some missing DLL files, which made sense because I omitted all the other files in `System32`. When I tried to to put the entire `C:\Windows\System32` folder on my hard drive, I again get something along the lines `Could not transfer files.`

I feel like I am stuck now. Could someone point me in a direction where to look next? I am pretty confident that the issue can be fixed because the Windows partition seems to be fine, but I don't know how to repair the bootloader. Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up with a solution to this? I've been down the same path and got as far as a blue recovery screen.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately not. In the end I saved all the personal data that I needed using a USB device and then reinstalled the OS. :( good luck